# Weird Value Change without Changing a Text File Python

Tags: python, file, loops, text, iteration

I am writing a program that is supposed to return the minimum sequence alignment score (smaller = better), and it worked with the Coursera sample inputs, but for the dataset we're given, I can't manually input the sequences, so I have to resort to using a textfile. There are a few things which I found weird.
First things first,

```
pattern = 'AAA'
DNA = open('practice_data.txt')
empty = []
for lines in DNA:
        line=lines.strip().strip('\n')
        empty.append(line)
print(empty)
print(smallest_distance(pattern, DNA))
```

If I run this, my program outputs 0. If I comment out for loop, my program outputs 2. I didn't change DNA, so why should my program behave differently? Also, my strip('\n') is working (and for some reason, strip('n') works just as well) but my strip() is not working. Once I figure this out, I can test out empty in my smallest_distance function.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
ACTAG
CTTAGTATCACTCTGAAAAGAGATTCCGTATCGATGACCGCCAGTTAATACGTGCGAGAAGTGGACACGGCCGCCGACGGCTTCTACACGCTATTACGATG AACCAACAATTGCTCGAATCCTTCCTCAAAATCGCACACGTCTCTCTGGTCGTAGCACGGATCGGCGACCCACGCGTGACAGCCATCACCTATGATTGCCG 
TTAAGGTACTGCTTCATTGATCAACACCCCTCAGCCGGCAATCACTCTGGGTGCGGGCTGGGTTTACAGGGGTATACGGAAACCGCTGCTTGCCCAATAAT

etc...
```

Comment: please give practice_data.txt . You can post on gist.github.com and give us the link here.

Comment: The `for` loop consumes `DNA`. If you comment it out, it doesn't. This is likely to make a difference to the `smallest_distance(pattern, DNA)` call.

Comment: [You may be interested in this CodeReview question.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135217/matlab-implementation-of-needleman-wunsch-algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
pattern = 'AAA'
with open('practice_data.txt') as f_dna:
    dna_list = [sequence for line in f_dna for sequence in line.split()]
print(smallest_distance(pattern, dna_list))
```

**Explanation:**

You were close to the solution, but you needed to remplace [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) by [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

-> `strip()` remove the extra characters, so your `strip('\n')` was a good guess.
But since `\n` is at the end of the line, split will automatically get rid of it because it is count as a delimitor

e.g

```
>>> 'test\ntest'.split()
>>> ['test', 'test']

>>> 'test\n'.split()
>>> ['test']
```

Now you have to remplace `.append()` by a simple addition between list operation since split returns a `list`.

```
DNA = open('practice_data.txt')
empty = []
for lines in DNA:
    line = lines.split()
    empty += line
```

**But**, there is still some problems in your code:

It is better to use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement while opening a file because it automatically handles exceptions and close the file descriptor at the end:

```
empty = []
with open('practice_data.txt') as DNA:  
    for lines in DNA:
        line = lines.split()
        empty += line
```

Your code is now fine, you can still refactor using list-comprehension (very common in python)

```
with open('practice_data.txt') as DNA:
    empty = [sequence for line in DNA for sequence in line.split()]
```

If you struggle understanding this; try to recompose it with for loop

```
empty = []
with open('practice_data.txt') as DNA:
    for line in DNA:
        for sequence in line.split():
            empty.append(sequence)
```

**Note**: @MrGeek solution works, but as two major defaults:

- as it is not using a `with` statement, the file is never closed, causing memory issue,
- using `.read().splitlines()` will load ALL the content of the file in memory, this could lead to `MemoryError` exception if the file is too big.

**Go further, handle huge file:**

Now imaging that you have a 1GO file filled with DNA sequences, even if you don't load all your file in memory, you still have a huge `dict`, a better pratice will be to create another file for the result and process your DNA on the fly:

e.g

```
pattern = 'AAA'
with open('practice_data.txt') as f_dna, open('result.txt', 'w') as f_result:
    for line in DNA:
        for sequence in line.split():
            result = smallest_distance(pattern, sequence)
            f_result.write(result)
```

**Warning**: You will have to make sure your function `smallest_distance` accepts a `string` rather than a `list`.

If not possible, you may need to process batch instead, but since it is a little complicated I will not talk of this here.

Now you can refactor a bit using for example a genetor function to improve readability

```
def extract_sequence(file, pattern):
    for line in file:
        for sequence in line.split():
            yield smallest_distance(pattern, sequence)

pattern = 'AAA'
with open('practice_data.txt') as f_dna, open('result.txt', 'w') as f_result:
    for result in extract_sequence(f_dna, pattern):
        f_result.write(result)
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thank you for taking the time to explain why even though certain methods work in getting the answer, they shouldn't be used for other reasons. And yes, I do understand list comprehension, but thanks anyway for being thorough!

Comment: @DrJessop, it was for me also, before writing nested list-comprehension, I always do the `for loop`s first and refactor afterward ^^' anyway Im glad you enjoy the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

potential errors:

```
print(smallest_distance(pattern, DNA))
```

DNA is file descriptor, not a string array. Because `DNA = open('practice_data.txt')`

For loop consume DNA. So, if you are using for loop `for lines in DNA:` again in smallest_distance, it doesn't work.

**Update:**
In this case, the for loop go from the beginning of file to the end. It would not go back again like a list. Unless you call `DNS.close()` and re-initialize file descriptor again `DNA = open('practice_data.txt')`

An simple example you can try

```
DNA = open('text.txt')
for lines in DNA:
        line=lines.strip().strip('\n')
        print (line) # print everything in the file here

print ('try again')
for lines in DNA:
        line=lines.strip().strip('\n')
        print (line) # will not print anything at all 

print ('done')
```

Read [For loop not working twice on the same file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561963/for-loop-not-working-twice-on-the-same-file-descriptor) for more detail

Comment: I keep hearing this word "consumes". What do you mean by that? Consumes system memory?

Comment: Thanks for the resource

Comment: In this context, "consumes" just means "reads lines from the file, one by one, until the entire file has been read".

Answer (score 0):

Write :

```
pattern = 'AAA'
DNA = open('practice_data.txt').read().splitlines()
newDNA = []
for line in DNA:
  newDNA += line.split() # create an array with strings then concatenate it with the newDNA array
print(smallest_distance(pattern, newDNA))
```

Comment: I attempted this, and for some reason I only get two strings in my list. One for the first line, and one for the rest

Comment: What role does empty play in here?

Comment: I wanted to create a list of all of the strings in the text file without having to manually input them.

Comment: There may be multiple strings on one line

Comment: how are the strings separated if they are on one line?

Comment: They are separated by a space. I tried using .strip() to get rid of this issue, but it isn't working

Comment: I figured out I need to use the replace method

Comment: glad to help :).